# ExpressionEngine FreeMember conditional return=''

Tags: conditionals, freemember

Attempting to return to different pages based on the success or failure of FreeMember Registration on Expression Engine.

The default attribute for the return URL is `return=''`, however I cannot seem to find any documentation relating to different return locations based on the successful or unsuccessful registering.

Through testing I have found that the URL within `return=''`will appear only on a successful completion of registration, however should you make an error within any part of the registration form then the URL goes back to `index.php` without any return path added.

**Q. Is there a specific custom attribute whereby you can define the URL for the unsuccessful completion of the register form?**

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your template code? As you mentioned, the `return` parameter only applies to a successful form submission. If the submission is unsuccessful (because of validation errors), you'll have to handle those. Are you using `error_handling="inline"`? If so, you'll need to actually include the error tags in the form (`{error:email}`). It would help to see your template code.